# setDate returns timestamp in jquery

Tags: jquery

Am trying to replace a day alone from the date

For ex

if the date entered by the user in 10/15/2016 means I need to change the day alone to 20 so that date may look like 10/20/2016

**Code**

```
var invoiceDate = $("#invDate").val();

      var invDates = new Date(invoiceDate);
                    var month = invDates.getMonth() + 1;
                    var date = invDates.setDate(15);
                    var year = invDates.getFullYear();
                    var formatDate =month  + '/' +
                        date + '/' +
                       year;
                    alert(formatDate);
```

am getting the date as 10/1476469800000/2016 but actually i need the day from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var invDates = new Date();
var month = invDates.getMonth() + 1;
invDates.setDate(15);
var year = invDates.getFullYear();
var formatDate =month  + '/' +
invDates.getDate()+ '/' +
year;

var newdate= new Date(formatDate);
alert(formatDate )
alert(newdate)

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when am parsing the formatedDate to new Date() am getting the invalid date  
var newDates = new Date(formatDate);
alert(newDates);

Comment: var newdate= new Date(formatDate);

$('#test').html(newdate);  Whts the problem with this code ?? have assigned and print it as u do . But i ddnt get any invalid date.

Comment: it returns invalid date in alert

Comment: I have done this but the 
var newdate= new Date(formatDate);
alert(formatDate )

Comment: is not working it alerts Invalid Date the new Date() is not working it seems will please check that

Comment: am getting Invalid date in alert :(

Answer (score 0):

you can user "getDate()" method to get the "Date" of the input date object.
for e.g.

```
var date = invdate.getDate(); //this will return 15.
```

then you can do any operation on it add days / remove days by normal subtraction and addition.

if your date part is fixed. for e.g. 20 as hard coded , then you can simply user

```
var date = 20;
```

This will also work.